# Obtrusive and regular requests in Firefox

Tags: firefox, kaspersky

I'm using Kaspersky Internet Security and haven't noticed this until today. While working on a local web project (localhost, port 3000) Firefox is doing external requests to ff.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com. I am sure this legitimate, but interestingly - Firefox doesn't do these requests inside other (public) web pages like superuser.com. Also - I don't have any Kaspersky extension inside Firefox. I don't see how would I disable this in KIS either. Chrome is not affected. For some reason Edge cannot open the project but that's certainly due to specifics in the project itself.

These requests are really obtrusive and are like half a second apart.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the Kaspersky add-on installed on Firefox.

The Kaspersky Labs post
[What is "ff.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com"](https://community.kaspersky.com/kaspersky-total-security-14/what-is-ff-kis-v2-scr-kaspersky-labs-com-1922)
says this:

> This is a fictitious address used by the Kaspersky AddOn to
>   communicate with KIS/KTS. The address is resolved on your computer, it
>   doesn't go outside. You can prevent the 'contact' by deactivating the
>   script injection. Then the KL addon loses parts of its function.
>
> Settings->Additional->Network', disable 'Inject script into web
>   traffic...'.

I don't know if this "problem" merits any fix.

Comment: since the traffic goes through a specific port I could add an exception for it (exceptions for domains or URLS are not possible). Settings -> Additional -> Network -> Control only specific ports, then add an inactive one